# How to pass a parameter and an event into a function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have had a (simple) problem I can't solve for a while. I don't know how to combine `myFunction1` and `myFunction2` into one function.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="link1">link1</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="link2">link2</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="link3">link3</a>

function myFunction1(val){
  console.log(val);
}
function myFunction2(e){
  console.warn('preventDefault');
  e.preventDefault();
}
/* this one doesn't work */
function myFunction3(val, e){
  console.log(val);
  console.warn('preventDefault');
  e.preventDefault();
}

document.getElementById('link1').onclick = function(e){
  myFunction1('hello');
};
document.getElementById('link2').onclick = function(e){
  myFunction2(e);
};
document.getElementById('link3').onclick = function(e){
  myFunction3(e, val);
};
```

So my question is simple, how do you get the third one to work. Work being: passing the val parameter and making the `preventDefault` work. So how do you combine `myFunction1` and `myFunction2` into one function?

Comment: `val` is `undefined` in third link's callback function. Also you messed up the order of arguments. Changing `myFunction3(e, val);` to `myFunction3("hello", e);` should work.

Comment: Oh, I really screwed that up. Sorry for that. I tried to distille the problem but made a stupid mistake. However, I still have the problem, see the less distilled React version here: https://codepen.io/lideebe/pen/EbqEWq?editors=1011

Comment: `e` of `render()` is `undefined` in that example.

Comment: I don't really understand. How do I fix it then? How do I get that preventDefault to work then?

Comment: You possibly want to have `onClick={this.handleClick}` and `handleClick(e){`. It's hard to say, I'm not familiar with react.

Comment: ok, thank you, will try it out. Thnx for your time.